# Python/Tkinter: Using custom mouse cursors under Windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, icons, tkinter

Python 2.7/Windows: My understanding is that we can load custom mouse cursors using the cursor='@file.cur' syntax:

```
widget = tkinter.Label( ..., cursor='@help.cur' )
```

Here's the traceback I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#82>", line 1, in <module>
    widget.config( cursor='@help.cur' )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1202, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1193, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: bad cursor spec "@help.cur"
```

Is it possible to load custom mouse cursors under Windows using Tkinter, a Tkinter extension, or via a Win32 API call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lbl=Label(root, text="toto", cursor="@toto.cur")` works for me on Python 2.6 and Vista. Make sure that the cur file is in the working directory of your script (I have a similar traceback if I try to load a non-existing cursor) and that the file is not corrupted.

As an alternative, here is a list of internal cursors: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/cursors.htm

Comment: Thank you Luc. The problem turned out to be trying to run my Tkinter code from within IDLE (I should have known better!). When I run the same script from the command line, the cursor='@/path/to/file.ext' technique works great.

Comment: is there a way to use ani extension cursors with tkinter