# tkinter - how to import windows cursors in widget's cursor options?

Tags: python, tkinter, qtextcursor

Here is a list of cursor options I have been able to find by creeping in a lot of websites:

`"arrow"
"circle"
"clock"
"cross"
"dotbox"
"exchange"
"fleur"
"heart"
"heart"
"man"
"mouse"
"pirate"
"plus"
"shuttle"
"sizing"
"spider"
"spraycan"
"star"
"target"
"tcross"
"trek"
"watch"`

This is my problem: I want to be able to access to all the cursor options that windows has available in its **pointer's customization settings** and **To Be Able To Use Them In My Gui**, And that's because .... the cursor options Tkinter provides does not suffices my needs to create a sophisticated gui,To sum up they are not sufficient and enough .

Look at below:(There are 189 pointers available)

[image: 189 pointers available !]

**My goal is to be able to make these pointers or mouse cursors shown ^^ABOVE^^, available to the tkinter's cursor options in the widgets I want, So that i can make those apps look like more to windows apps.**

These are my wonders:

- should i change the tkinter's package code or make changes to the directory it gets these cursors or
  pointers images from; to the directory windows pointers or cursors are ?
- is there any built-in option to do so ? for example a class sophisticated for this purpose (the customization of cursors available)?

***If you have any suggestions please don't hesitate to give any suggestions.***

Comment: For a more complete list of cursors for tkinter, you can have a look at the tcl/tk [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/cursors.htm)

Comment: @j_4321, thanks, I hope windows cursors can be found in the tkinter's accessible cursors.

Comment: Otherwise, it seems to be possible to load cursors, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049612/python-tkinter-using-custom-mouse-cursors-under-windows

Comment: @stovfl, sounds similar, thanks.