# Python tkinter how can I set the cursor as an image

Tags: python, tkinter, cursor

**I want the cursor to be an image when hovering over my canvas, when i run this it gives me 'bad cursor spec "pyimage1"' error. Is it possible?**

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500+0+0')

custom_cursor = PhotoImage(file='custom_cursor.png')

canvas = Canvas(root, height=50, width=50, bg='black', cursor=custom_cursor)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think maybe you couldn't use normal format image but a image with cursor format,Read about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049612/python-tkinter-using-custom-mouse-cursors-under-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use an image as a cursor. At least, not directly. The `cursor` option must be one of the following:

- the name of a standard X11 cursor (see [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/cursors.htm) for a list of valid cursor names)
- the path to a file in the X11 or X10 cursor format
- on Windows only, the path to a .ani or .cur file

The definitive description of the `cursor` option is on the tcl/tk man page for [Tk_GetCursor](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/GetCursor.htm)

Since you are using a canvas, you can simulate a cursor with an image by drawing a normal image and updating it's position whenever the cursor moves, though it would lag very slightly being the real cursor.